# Apache POI - error in reading excel file

Tags: apache, excel, file, apache-poi

I am using poi-3.5-beta5 to read excel file.
I am trying to open excel file through 
 XSSFWorkbook workBook = new XSSFWorkbook (xlsPath);

i am getting following error (although i am not using log4j)

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/log4j/Logger
 at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.Package.(Package.java:63)
 at org.apache.poi.POIXMLDocument.openPackage(POIXMLDocument.java:63)
 at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook.(XSSFWorkbook.java:173)
 at test.ExcelReader.displayFromExcel(ExcelReader.java:44)
 at test.ExcelReader.main(ExcelReader.java:138)

Please help me to sole this problem.
Thanks

Answer (score 3):

POI probably has a dependency on log4j. Just include the log4j jar in your classpath.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you need [Log4J](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/index.html) on your classpath.

Answer (score 1):

poi-3.5-beta?
They have release POI 3.7, it's stable, and powerful. Plus they have a new package called SS (SpreadSheet), it can handdle both HSSF and XSSF files without worrying about type

Details: http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/converting.html

Answer (score 0):

If U have that problem still, I want to give you some information:

May be you might not include `poi-ooxml-version.jar` file.

Since you're processing Excel format 2007, the `XSSF` Format implementations are included in this jar file...